# Shutdown / reboot linux machine from flutter app

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, std

Supposedly in C after importing `<stdlibc.h>` you can invoke method `system()` an pass a param to perform shutdown. But using this as C script passed to flutter button via ffi does not seem to work. There is a package [stdlibc for flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/stdlibc) but it doesn't have the system() function. It has close() function but there isn't a good documentation on what fildes stand for what process. Maybe killing the main system process would also work but it's hard to determine what param to pass to perform that.

What would be the cleanest and safest way to shutdown and reboot linux machine programatically from a flutter app?

Comment: Any specific reason for not calling e.g. `shutdown` or `systemctl poweroff` / `systemctl reboot` using `Process`? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-io/Process-class.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';


Future<void> shutdown({bool restart = false, int delay = 0}) {
  final params = <String>[];

  if (restart) {
    params.add('-r');
  }

  params.addAll(<String>['-t', delay.toString(), 'now']);

  return Process.run('shutdown', params);
}
```